# how to get values from file using sed,awk or grep on linux command/scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

i have file1 with value:

```
<action>
 <row>
    <column name="book" label="book">stick man (2020)/</column>
    <column name="referensi" label="referensi"> http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/1%20Stick%20%282020%30/</column>
 </row>
<row>
    <column name="book" label="book">python easy (2019)/</column>
    <column name="referensi" label="referensi"> http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/2%20Buck%20%282019%30/</column>
 </row>
</action>
```

i want to get the contents of the file using linux scripting or command (sed, grep or awk). example output:

```
stick man (2020) | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/1%/20Stick%20%282020%30
python easy (2019) | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/%2/20Buck%20%282019%30
```

my code:

```
grep -oP 'href="([^".]*)">([^</.]*)' file1
```

please help i am newbie :)

Comment: [Do not parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use xmllint or xmlstarlet. Use python ruby perl languages with xml support and other xml-aware tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='<[^>]+>' 'NF{printf "%s", $0 (++c%2?" |":ORS)}' file

stick man (2020)/ | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/1%20Stick%20%282020%30/
python easy (2019)/ | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/2%20Buck%20%282019%30/
```

note that forward slashes are in your original data

requires multi-char `RS` support (GNU awk).

Comment: The output shown doesn't match the example output in the OP. He's looking for e.g. `stick man (2020) | http ...` not `stick man (2020)/ | http ...`, noting the `/` after the `)` is not wanted.

Comment: I"m almost sure his sample data has copy/paste errors or typos.  There is no need to remove non-existent chars since there is no mention of trimming them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<action>
 <row>
    <column name="book" label="book">stick man (2020)/</column>
    <column name="referensi" label="referensi"> http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/1%20Stick%20%282020%30/</column>
 </row>
<row>
    <column name="book" label="book">python easy (2019)/</column>
    <column name="referensi" label="referensi"> http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/2%20Buck%20%282019%30/</column>
 </row>
</action>
```

does looks like piece of HTML file. If you are allowed to install utilites in your system I suggest giving a try [hxselect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/hxselect.1.html) which is useful when you want to extract something you can describe in CSS language. For example to get content of all `column`s whose `label` is `referensi` from `file.html`:

```
cat file.html | hxselect -i -c -s '\n' column[label=referensi]
```

Comment: Can the `hxselect` _command_ be written to produce the output shown ion the OP?  I ask because the example as coded just returns the **URL** not e.g. `stick man (2020) | http ...`.

Comment: @user3439894 I doubt `hxselect` itself is able to do so, however it should be relatively easy to process after extracting data using that tool

Comment: So if I understand your response to my question in the previous comment, and using the _data_ in the OP, I'd have to call `hxselect` twice and process its output with additional normal utilities. If that's the case, then with  different _data_ having many _targets_ it's not a very practical utility. Anyway thanks for your response and it's nice to have another _tool_ to work.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can try:

```
awk -F'>|/<'  '{ORS= (NR == 3 || NR == 7) ? " |" : "\n"} $2 != "" {print $2}' file
stick man (2020) | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/1%20Stick%20%282020%30
python easy (2019) | http://172.22.215.234/Data/Book/Journal/2016_2020/2%20Buck%20%282019%30
```

- Or shorter:

```
awk -F'>|/<'  '{ORS= (NR%2) ? " |" : RS} $2 != "" {print $2}' file
```

Comment: This does work based solely on the example in the OP, however, I have to agree with KamilCuk's comment made to the OP.

Comment: Yes, that tool or similar would be the correct way.